# C - Void pointer and offset

Tags: c, pointers

Say I have a void pointer (more like; array), and I want to get the items inside it. 
So, I know that pointer[i] won't work since it's void and I don't know the type; I tried using the offset technique:

```
void function(void* p, int eltSize){
  int offset = 3;
  for(i = 0; i<offset; i++){
   memcpy(p+(i*eltsize), otherPointer, eltSize);//OtherPointer has same type.
  } 
  //End function
}
```

This function works good and everything, but the only problem is that at the end of main(..) I get segmentation fault. I know it's because of the pointer and how I accessed the items of it, but I don't know how to correct the problem and avoid segmentation fault.

Comment: If you do not know what is it (the type) at the address location, you cannot use it...

Comment: `p + (I*eltsize)` this could would not compile at all. The compiler cannot do pointer arithmetics on void pointers.

Comment: @Morovaille, `qsort` doesn't know the type and it works.

Comment: @AlterMann what are you talking about ? `qsort` use a user's function for sorting. I hope the user knows the type of his data.

Comment: @Morovaille, this user function is called by `qsort` to compare two elements, but how can it move between the elements using a `void *` as base? using a chunk of bytes, see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by @sunqingyao and @flutter, you can not use arithmetic with `void` pointers in Standard C; instead, use a `char *` (a chunk of bytes a la `qsort`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void function(void *ptr, size_t eltSize, void *otherPointer, size_t offset)
{
    char *p = ptr;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < offset; i++) {
        memcpy(p + (i * eltSize), otherPointer, eltSize);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
    int otherValue = 4;

    function(arr, sizeof *arr, &otherValue, sizeof arr / sizeof *arr);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But; what if the ptr points to a struct? Should it work even though we used it as a char pointer? And I saw many posts talking about this char* pointer. Can you please point to the "trick" used here (casting void* to char*). Thank you.

Comment: No problem using `struct`s instead of primitive types, take a look to [this thread](https://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/618725-void-vs-char), `void *` and `char *` are functionally equivalent, the key property of both is that they are pointers that can be faithfully cast to any other pointer type. It is legal to perform arithmetic on a `char *`, but not on a `void *`.

Comment: Great. Thank you so much. gonna try this asap!

Comment: Don't you have to typecast the void pointer to a char pointer?

Comment: @laptop2d: You don't need to, you can assign to a generic `char *` at the very begin and perform pointer arithmetic over it, as done. Another way (what you say) is passing/casting a `char *` to `function();`: https://ideone.com/t0rXWf

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from N1570 6.5.6 Additive operators(emphasis mine):

> 2 For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or
>   one operand shall be a pointer to **a complete object type** and the
>   other shall have integer type. (Incrementing is equivalent to adding
>   1.)

Obviously, `void` isn't a complete object type. Thus, applying `+` operator on `void *` invokes undefined behaviour, which may result in segmentation fault or anything else.

One approach to solve your problem would be declaring parameter `p` as a `char *`.